# Эквивалент regex для java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/", "", $text);
preg_replace('#<br[/\s]*>#si', "\n", $text);
```

Первая удаляет отступы в начале текста в виде 
 тегов.
Вторая заменяет оставшиеся отступы.
Попробовал так:

```
 text = text.replaceAll("(^)?(<br\\s*\\/?>\\s*)+$", "");
 text = text.replaceAll("<br[/\\s]*>", "");
```

К сожалению, не работает замена в первом случае, во втором сработала, мб лишняя экранизация?

UPD.
Рабочий вариант:

```
full_text = full_text.replaceAll("^(?:\\s+|<br\\s*\\/?>)+", "");
full_text = full_text.replaceAll("<br[/\\s]*>", "");
```

Comment: а можно пример текста для первого случая и что должно получиться?

Comment: пожалуйста, оформите ваше решение в виде ответа, или удалите вопрос вовсе.